# String concatenation in C?

Tags: c, c-strings

I am trying to understand string's behavior in C and it is bothering me since my following two code snippets result into different output:
(For the sake of this question, Let us assume user enters 12)

```
int main(void)  
{
    char L_Red[2];
    char temp[] = "I";
    printf("Enter pin connected to red: ");
    scanf("%s", L_Red);
    strcat(temp,L_Red);
    printf("%s \n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

this yields: 12 as output (and not I12) Why ?

```
int main(void)  
{
    char L_Red[2];
    printf("Enter pin connected to red: ");
    scanf("%s", L_Red);
    char temp[] = "I";
    strcat(temp,L_Red);
    printf("%s \n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

This yields: I12I (and not, I12) Why ?

I have read about string in C and as per my understanding, neither am I allocating temp any fixed size and changing it later to get these vague outputs nor am I using strings like the way they are not supposed to. Is there any other concept at play here ?

Comment: Many duplicates. Your `temp` array is too small to hold the result of your concatenation, so you're writing over the end of the array. You certainly are allocating a `temp` a fixed size (size 2 in both cases), you're just doing so implicitly.

Comment: I have tried with temp[100] as well, it sill doest work.
I read all the duplicates and still couldnt figure out what is wrong because I am doing concatenation now like most of the accepted answers here.

Comment: You'll also need more space for `L_Red` if you're trying to store two characters plus the null terminator in there (i.e. at least 3, not 2).

Comment: This worked by can you explain this please ?
My doubt: If I declare char L_Red[2] and print it, I see the desired out put (12 in this case).
Concatenation is adding to char temp[] which has enough space. I am printing temp then how does increasing size of L_Red working in this case for concatenation ?

Comment: There's generally not much point here trying to understand why programs exhibiting undefined behavior sometimes appear to "work". It depends upon the code that your compiler emits, and when your program exhibits undefined behavior, there aren't any restrictions on what that code can be. The important thing is that strange things can happen when you overwrite the bounds of your arrays, and one of those strange things can sometimes be your program appearing to work as you might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `temp` is an array of *two* characters (the `'I'` and the string terminator `'\0'`). That's it. Attempting to append more characters to that array will write *out of bounds* and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make sure that the destination array `temp` have enough space to fit its original content *plus* the string you want to append (plus the terminator).

---

Also, if you want to input more than one character for the "string" `L_Red` you need to increase its size as well.

I also recommend you use a limit in the format specifier so you *can't* write out of bounds:

```
char L_Red[3];  // Space for two characters, plus terminator
scanf("%2s", L_Red);  // Read at most two characters of input
```

Comment: I have tried using temp[100], this still doesnt work.

Comment: @Moose Because you still have *undefined behavior* as you input two characters into an array that can only hold a one-character string! Don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is important, and needs space as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  In example 1st of the code: Appending more characters will definitely cause writing out of bounding however for sure `I` will always be there in `temp`. The output should be **I12.** and not just 12.

Comment: @ZahidKhan Undefined behavior is, well, *undefined*. Sometimes it can cause crashes, sometimes it might seem to work, and sometimes it might cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). What probably happens in reality, is that you overwrite parts of the stack, perhaps even overwrite the contents of the array `L_Red`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting strange answers because your destination string (ie the first argument to strcat) is not long enough to handle both strings plus a null termination character. Also the length of L_Red is  too short as it does not have enough space for the null termination character either.